# "Hall of mirrors" OR "wrapped plane" - Problem

Tags: geometry

If we Imagine a finite plane such as a quad there's nothing special with it BUT if we imagine that if some Object reaches its edge it disappears from the edge and appears on the other side.
A Scenario like this can displayed as following sketch:

[image: Infinitely Mirrored 2D-Space]

The problem is now:

- When i'm sending out a ray from the point (x,y) into the scene with a arbitrary angle (alpha), **how can I determine IF and in wich distance the ray hits the point itselfe** ?

[image: Ray coincideion]

**In addition is there a ~average distance between 2 points. In Rn  !**
My assumption is that there IS One because the Vektor Sum of all infinite Vectors from the Point to itself has to be ZERO (or not?) !

What's the code for Wolfram alpha?

Comment: The ray would always have a fixed angle. It can only coincide but never intersect.

Comment: Thanks for that correction !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your fundamental domain is the rectangle $[0,a]\times[0,b]$. Its universal cover is then the plane with two points $z_1$, $z_2$ equivalent iff $z_1-z_2\in a{\mathbb Z}\>\times\> b{\mathbb Z}$. In order to find out when a ray closes up on itself it is sufficient to consider rays emanating from $(0,0)$. "Closing up" means that the ray hits a lattice point $(ma, nb)\ne(0,0)$ in finite time. For this to happen it is necessary and sufficient that the ray is vertical, or that its slope $\alpha\in\ \bigl]-{\pi\over2},{\pi\over2}\bigr[\ $ satisfies
$$\tan\alpha={n\over m}\>{b\over a}\ .$$
When $a=b$ this means that $\tan\alpha$ should be rational. When $m$ and $n$ are in lowest terms then the length of the loop so created will be $\sqrt{m^2a^2 +n^2 b^2}$.

In order to compute the average distance (a number!) between two random points you may assume  the first point being $(0,0)$ and the second uniformly distributed in the rectangle $\bigl[0,{a\over2}\bigr]\times\bigl[0,{b\over2}\bigr]$. This simplification is due to translational and mirror symmetry of the whole setup.  The mean distance is then given by the double integral
$$d_{\rm mean}={4\over ab}\int_0^{a/2}\int_0^{b/2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\>dy\>dx\ ,$$
which is a pain to compute. The factor ${4\over ab}$ is the reciprocal area of the rectangle $\bigl[0,{a\over2}\bigr]\times\bigl[0,{b\over2}\bigr]$.

When $a=b=1$ Mathematica produces the following value for the average distance:
$$d_{\rm mean}={\sqrt{2}+{\rm arsinh}(1)\over 6}\ .$$

Comment: i know i have to open a new Question but I'm to lazy to "reask". Do you kow how you can determine the direction of the Vektor between the above descibed points ? Is it a integral too ? Sorry for asking that in this context, if it's better to modifie the question above , let me know.

Comment: @schwenk: My answer fully addresses and answers the question "When I'm sending out a ray from the point $(x,y)$ into the scene with an arbitrary angle $\alpha$, **how can I determine if and in wich distance the ray hits the point itselfe** ?".

Comment: what is the "average distance vector" between these two points if I'm having 4 quadrants ?